# Setting initial value for primary key in Rails (i.e. first object's id is 1000 instead of 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the best way of going about this.  Is there something I can put in the migrations?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is database specific. Just do something like the following in your migration:

```
class MyMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :my_table do |t|
      # ...
    end
    execute "ALTER TABLE my_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000" # for MySQL
  end

  def self.down
    # ...
  end
end
```

Or indeed, even better, as suggested by Bane:

```
  def self.up
    create_table :my_table, :options => "AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000" do |t|
      # ...
    end
  end
```

Be cautious with database-specific migrations, though! Using any SQL that is specific to your database will break compatibility with other databases and is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Migrations should be database independent. What if the database you are running migration on doesn't support that option? The execution will probably raise an exception. I would run the command directly on the database instead. BTW, I agree with the solution.

Comment: @weppos, running it directly on a database will rob you of the advantage of migrations that they can be used to easily port your database schema to other servers. Of course, the other major advantage, porting to a database from a different vendor, will be void.

Comment: Hi molf, you're missing a double quote before AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: And of course one can argue that setting the auto-increment value is not actually part of the db schema. Because it is apparently a requirement in this case I would assert this behaviour in a test case somewhere. In which case it would be necessary in the migrations as well.

Answer (score 9):

Any string passed into the ":options" option will be appended to the end of the SQL statement that creates the table. Best practice.

```
def self.up
    create_table :my_table, :options => "AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000" do |t|
      # ...
    end
end
```